# Comparing input value with value of an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-validation

I have a problem with the validation about existing values. I don't know how to compare two values and add the new value only, when it isn't exist in the Database. I've tried with `angular.forEach()` but it adds the new object always when the compare (what I'm doing with `angular.equals()`) isn't false and thats wrong. The object have to be only one time in the database.

Here is my create function:

```
$scope.createItem = function (createItem) {
   //here I have to define a query to compare createItem.lname with the table list (array items from the db) in the view.

   //That was the code:
   angular.forEach(nameslist, function (value) {
     if (angular.equals(createItem.lname, value.lname)) {
           CrudService.create(createItem).then(
              function () {
                //success code
                $scope.createItem = null;
              },
              function (err) {
               //error code
              });
           }
     }
   });
}
```

Can anyone give me some help.. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Where is your comparison code?

Comment: @tymeJV I've added my post

Comment: Is `lname` just a string?

Comment: @tymeJV is a property of the object. It is a string yes. `nameslist` is the array with the objects from the database

Comment: So why not just `if (createItem.lname === value.lname) {` - `angular.equals` is for object comparison

Comment: @tymeJV Because when I'm using `angular.forEach()` then it compares to every object. that means I have 40 objects in the database. If the lname exists, then it creates 39 times the new object and one time returns a error. That is the problem what I have currently.

Comment: @yuro why not leave the creation logic to the backend? If your front-end has no way of knowing the state, then it's extra work to keep validating with the front-end and back-end. Keep the validation to backend only.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemAbsent = namelist.map(function(value){
   return value.name;
}).indexOf(createItem.name) < 0;

if (nameAbsent){
   CrudService.create(createItem).then(
          function () {
            //success code
            $scope.createItem = null;
          },
          function (err) {
           //error code
          });
       }
}
```